# Issue with analyzing strings in Python for Wordle-esque progam

Tags: python

I've created a function that takes a user-inputted guess, compared it to a hidden word taken randomly from a word doc, and returns a string that indicates if any letters match or are in the word at all. Here is the function:

```
def wordResults(guess, testGuess):
#guess = user inputted guess
#testGuess = secret word
    
    results = ""
    
    for i in range(5):

#Check if letters at given position match
#in each word, append capital letter if so
        if guess[i] == testGuess[i]:
            results += guess[i].upper()

#Check if letter at given position is in
#the secret word at all, append lowercase
#letter if so
        elif testGuess.find(guess[i]) != -1:
            results += guess[i]

#Append underscore if neither condition is met
        else:
            results += "_"
                
     return results
```

My issue lies with the elif-statement. I would like it to print a lowercase only if that letter appears in the word, but not if the letter is already in the correct spot. Here is the program running to show what I'm referring to:

(Note: the hidden word is also user-inputted until I get the program working as intended)

[image]

For Guess #2, I would like it so that the first 'h' does not show up, since it is indicating the 5th letter in 'conch' that is already confirmed with a capital 'H'. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to work with a list and then make it a string at the end:

```
guess = guess.lower()
testGuess = testGuess.lower()
result = []
for i, letter in enumerate(guess):
    if letter in testGuess:
        if letter == testGuess[i]:
            result.append(letter)
        else:
            result.append(letter.upper())
    else:
        result.append('_')

for i, letter in enumerate(result):
    if letter.upper() in result and result[i] != letter:
        result[i] = '_'

return ''.join(result)
```

For guess two, then the second loop checks if each letter is already in the loop and placed correctly and if it's not in the correct spot, makes it back into an `_`.